# DeleteALLByID not existe an other table CrudRepository

Tags: spring-data, crud-repository

What is the correct syntax with spring date ( Crud repository ) to said delete from table A where a.id not exist in select distinct b.id_A from b in the interface ARepository some thing like : deleteAllbyIdIsNotIn...

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use the predefined functions in crud repository, my need is to delete all rows from a table where its id does not exist in another table